# Let X, a metric space show that if $A, B⊂X$ are complete, then $A∪B$ is complete.

Tags: general-topology

Let X, a metric space show that if $A, B⊂X$ are complete, then $A∪B$ is complete.

Let X, a metric space show that if ...
Would it be okay to demonstrate like this ?:

Let $ {x_ {n_m}} _ {m_∈N}$ be the given sub-succession contained in A because it is a Cauchy sequence, in A, then it would converge towards a point $ a∈A $

$∀ϵ>0,∃v_1∈N,∀m≥v_1:d(x_{n_m},a)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

On the other hand, since   ${x_n}_{n∈N}$ is a Cauchy sequence

$∃v_2∈N,∀n,n´≥v_2:d(x_n,x_n´)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

soon $v=max(v_1,v_2)$ con lo que se verifica $n_v≥n_{v_1}$  y  $n_v≥n_{v_2≥v_2}$  soon

$∀n≥v:d(x_n,a)≤d(x_n,x_{n_v}+d(x_{n_v},a)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$

namely; the entire sequence${x_n}_{n∈N}$ converges towards a
If not, I need help to prove it please.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is rather simple, and it seems you are on the right track of turning the sequence into a subsequence fully contained in either $A$ or $B$. The basic idea is like this: let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $A \cup B$. Then there must exist a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ that is entirely inside $A$ or entirely inside $B$ (since if not, then both $A$ and $B$ would contain a finite number of terms in the sequence, meaning also $A\cup B$ would, which is a contradiction).

Without loss of generality, let us assume our subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\mathbb N}$ is contained in $A$. Since $A$ is complete, and a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence is still Cauchy, $x_{n_k}\to x$ for some $x \in A$. However, it is a well-known property that a Cauchy sequence with a convergent subsequence is itself convergent with the same limit (try and prove this). Thus $x_n\to x$ for $x \in A \cup B$, meaning $A\cup B$ is complete.